# Collectors lambda return observable list

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, observablelist, collectors

Is it possible for Collectors to return me a ObservableArrayList? A little like this:

```
ObservableList<String> newList = list.stream().
        filter(x -> x.startsWith("a").
        collect(Collectors.toCollection(ObservableArrayList::new));
```

Comment: You just did it, didn't you?

Comment: @assylias Nope, there is no constructor for `ObservableArrayList` (it isn't event a class actually)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`ObservableList`s are created with the static factories from the [`FXCollections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html) class.

As noted by Louis Wasserman [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849538/collectors-lambda-return-observable-list/33849644?noredirect=1#comment55464064_33849644), this can be done using `toCollection`:

```
ObservableList<String> newList = 
        list.stream()
            .filter(x -> x.startsWith("a"))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(FXCollections::observableArrayList));
```

You could also do the following, which first collects the stream into a `List` and then wraps it inside an `ObservableList`.

```
ObservableList<String> newList = 
        list.stream()
            .filter(x -> x.startsWith("a"))
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(toList(), l -> FXCollections.observableArrayList(l)));
```

(which unfortunately enough does not compile on Eclipse Mars 4.5.1 but compiles fine on `javac` 1.8.0_60).

Another possibility is to create a custom Collector for this. This has the advantage that there is no need to first use a `List`. The elements are directly collected inside a `ObservableList`.

```
ObservableList<String> newList = 
        list.stream()
            .filter(x -> x.startsWith("a"))
            .collect(Collector.of(
                FXCollections::observableArrayList,
                ObservableList::add,
                (l1, l2) -> { l1.addAll(l2); return l1; })
            );
```

Comment: that last expression looks nasty. Thanks

Comment: @Josephus87 The static imports help a bit. Also, I added a second possibility which does not use an intermediate list.

Comment: Why not just `collect(toCollection(FXCollections::observableArrayList))`, which solves both problems?

Comment: Ah wonderful, works like a charm. This lambda stuff is not really my thing (yet) :D. I'd pick a for loop just out of reflex

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes, you're right. Weirdly it didn't cross my mind. Is it ok if I edit that in? You could post your own answer

Comment: @Tunaki I made a typo. How do I know what to place in front of the :: and after it. It seems to be a bunch of unordered rules.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(FXCollections::observableArrayList))` in the last line? I think `Collectors` is missing there.